# Providing an (empty) user-defined destructor causes compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, destructor, unique-ptr

Code which compiles perfectly fine (on GCC 4.7.2) when I do not have a user-defined destructor, produces errors when even an *empty* user-defined destructor is provided:

```
#include <memory>

class Test
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> val;
};

template <typename Type>
class B
{
public:
   //destructor:
   // if I comment this out, the code compiles just fine:
   ~B() { }

private:
   Test a;
};

int main()
{
   auto s = B<int>();
}
```

The salient points in the error produced when the destructor is not commented out are:

- The copy constructor for Test does not exist, and was not implicitly created because it would be ill formed
- Something tried to use the deleted copy constructor for unique_ptr.

The complete error output, for anyone interested, is at the bottom of this post.

I am of aware that `unique_ptr` cannot be copy constructed (unless the argument is an rvalue), and thus that it is not possible for the compiler to generate a valid implicit copy constructor for the class `Test`.

What I cannot figure out is why defining even an **empty** destructor should suddenly require these copy facilities. Obviously, when things like `unique_ptr`s are used, this isn't possible to provide.

Would anyone here be able to enlighten me as to why this is the case?

**Complete error output when the destructor is not commented out:**

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/list:64:0,
                 from ../../Dropbox/Programming/C++/test/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h: In instantiation of 'std::_List_node<_Tp>::_List_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const Test&}; _Tp = Test]':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:110:4:   required from 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::_List_node<Test>; _Args = {const Test&}; _Tp = std::_List_node<Test>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:503:8:   required from 'std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Node* std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const Test&}; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Node = std::_List_node<Test>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:1533:63:   required from 'void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const Test&}; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<Test>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:997:9:   required from 'void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Test]'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:1466:6:   required from 'void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = std::_List_const_iterator<Test>; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:582:9:   required from 'std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::list(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::list<Test>]'
../../Dropbox/Programming/C++/test/main.cpp:11:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_list.h:115:71: error: use of deleted function 'Test::Test(const Test&)'
../../Dropbox/Programming/C++/test/main.cpp:5:7: note: 'Test::Test(const Test&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
../../Dropbox/Programming/C++/test/main.cpp:5:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/memory:86:0,
                 from ../../Dropbox/Programming/C++/test/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/unique_ptr.h:262:7: error: declared here
```

Comment: Aah that's good to know; I was under the impression that whether implicit move constructors/assignment operators were created or not was still hit and miss depending on the compiler or something. I didn't realise it was part of the standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you define `~B()`, this suppresses the move constructor of `B`, so the compiler tries to generate a copy constructor but fails because `unique_ptr` is not copy-constructible.

If you omit `~B()`, the move constructor of `B` is generated and is used in `main`.

You can request the automatically generated move constructor:

```
B(B &&) = default;
```

This is a feature in the standard for backwards compatibility with C++03 code; per the Rule of Three, code that writes its own destructor (etc.) is assumed to be managing its own resources so automatically generating a move constructor would not be appropriate unless explicitly requested.

Comment: Am I right in thinking then, that the line `auto s = B<int>();` first constructs a temporary B, then calls B's implicit move assignment operator (in s), which in turn calls B's implicit move constructor?

Comment: @lytnus `auto s = B<int>()` is an *initialization*, not an assignment, so calls a constructor (although the constructor call can be elided, it must be available).

Comment: Note that if you don't fall in the new *`auto` everywhere* trend and just type `B<int> s;` There won't be any need for a definition of either the move or copy constructors. I find it funny how `auto` was created to reduce typing and is suddenly used to type more...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: +1 Tell me about it

Comment: Yeah, I am actually used to declaring things that way round from Javascript, so in fact that was just an error on my part more than anything; but on the plus side it led to me learning some stuff from here, so it's all good!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you said it yourself; when you provide a user-defined destructor, you inhibit the compiler's ability to generate things like an implicit move constructor. The *contents* of your user-defined destructor (be it empty or otherwise) are completely irrelevant.

> `[C++11: 12.7/9]:` **If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if**:
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - **`X` does not have a user-declared destructor**, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
>
> *[ Note:* **When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that otherwise would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor.** *—end note ]*

The text in the note points out the exact case that you are seeing, leading to a compilation failure because `unique_ptr` *cannot* be copied; although *you're* not copying it, and although the initialisation of `s` may not require a copy/move, the operation is still required to be available (per `[C++11: 12.8/31-32]`).

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that the move constructor is implicitly defined as part of the standard; I was under the impression that it was hit and miss whether the compiler opted to do that for you or not (though I'm sure I would have still been confused regardless!)

Comment: @lytnus you may have gotten that impression because MSVC is missing that implicit generation.

Comment: Yeah; frankly it's hit and miss as to whether or not MSVC will opt to do _anything_ for you, these days.